# Banner in JS, " animation " part not working?

Tags: javascript

```js
var sponsor = 1;

function goBanner() {
  if (sponsor == 1) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.pavucina.sk";
  }
  if (sponsor == 2) {
    window.location.href = "http://forum.sk";
  }
  if (sponsor == 3) {
    window.location.href = "http://superzoznam.sk";
  }
}

function rotate() {
  if (++sponsor > 3) sponsor = 1;
  document.images[0].src = "" + sponsor + ".jpg"
  window.setTimeout('rotate();', 5000);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:goBanner();"><img class="slikaF" name="banner" src="1.png" border=0></a>
```

I need to use this code specificly but i do not understnd why isnt my banner working. Links in banner are functional but image "animatio" isnt. Pls help

Comment: Please format the question properly and edit the tag to JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Where do you ever call the `rotate()` function?

Comment: @achAmháin Java was a mistype i apologize

Comment: ˇ@David that is the scheme of the code i am soposed to do it. I gave you the same instruction that i got. I am cracking my head with it a few hours and i do not get it. any help would relly br good.

Comment: You can not expect us to be able to fix your issues that relate to external code or instructions you have been given, when we don’t even know what those are. If you have insufficient information from whoever gave this to you, then you should ask _them_ about it first of all. If you need our help, then the least you need to do is provide a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You never invoke the `rotate` function.  Instead of using `setTimeout` inside the function to keep re-invoking itself (without first invoking it to start that process), call [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) once from outside the function.  Something like this:

```
function rotate() {
  if (++sponsor > 3) sponsor = 1;
  document.images[0].src = "" + sponsor + ".jpg"
}

window.setInterval(rotate, 5000);
```

This will invoke the `rotate` function repeatedly in 5-second intervals.

For example:

```js
var sponsor = 1;

function goBanner() {
  if (sponsor == 1) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.pavucina.sk";
  }
  if (sponsor == 2) {
    window.location.href = "http://forum.sk";
  }
  if (sponsor == 3) {
    window.location.href = "http://superzoznam.sk";
  }
}

function rotate() {
  if (++sponsor > 3) sponsor = 1;
  document.images[0].src = "" + sponsor + ".jpg"
}

window.setInterval(rotate, 5000);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:goBanner();"><img class="slikaF" name="banner" src="1.png" border=0></a>
```

Comment: I just tryed that, does not work.  -  The links in a banner are rotating every 5 sec as well nad that does work only image is a problem

Comment: @TheStwor: What specifically isn't working?  The snippet in the answer is changing the image `src` as expected.  Do you have an example which isn't doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `rotate` function.

You have to remove the timeOut from within the function and keep it separatelly.

```
function rotate() {
  if (++sponsor > 3) sponsor = 1;
  document.images[0].src = "" + sponsor + ".jpg"
}

window.setInterval(rotate, 5000);
```

Now, the `rotate` function are only counting the `sponsor` variable and changing the `src` of the image. We are calling the function through the `setInterval`: it will **init** and execute the next calls for every 5 seconds.

Check the fiddle below:

```js
var sponsor = 1;

function goBanner() {
  if (sponsor == 1) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.pavucina.sk";
  }
  if (sponsor == 2) {
    window.location.href = "http://forum.sk";
  }
  if (sponsor == 3) {
    window.location.href = "http://superzoznam.sk";
  }
}

function rotate() {
  if (++sponsor > 3) sponsor = 1;
  document.images[0].src = sponsor + ".jpg";
  document.images[0].title = "Image " + sponsor;
}

window.setInterval(rotate, 3000);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Banner</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:goBanner();"><img class="slikaF" name="banner" src="1.jpg" title="Image 1" border="0"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Ps: added a `title` attribute to the images, since we are not displaying here the original files and it could be difficult to see the transitions.

I hope it helps.